# What ultimately happens to mining if blocks contain mostly non-Bitcoin data?

Tags: mining-reward, merged-mining, mining-profitability

I'm trying to understand what can happen if

- A block consists entirely of 3rd party (xCoin) data like Namecoin
- There are no Tx fees to collect since they are on alternate chains.
- Assume that the Block reward is quite low (0.25 BTC).

How will mining be profitable?

If the 3rd party data must subsidize mining, what would that subsidy look like within a block?

Comment: Exchange rate would be 1000 USD per BTC, so 250 USD per block is not bad.. :)

Comment: @vi.su [citation needed]

Comment: @makerofthings "A block consists entirely of 3rd party (xCoin) data like Namecoin" NameCoin merged mining adds 32 bytes - which is about 1/5 of one transaction.

Comment: @NickODell Just as Namecoin was invented as an alt chain, what I create one, and then some state does as well.  Add a few others and the quantity of bytes increases....

Comment: If a transaction (e.g., xCoin, your example) isn't "paying the freight" it will be cast aside (e.g., take longer to confirm.)   If system-wide fees are lower, mining capacity drops to match.  That's not a problem unless 51% is a real concern, and that's not a real concern now.

Comment: Bitcoin reward would be 0.25 BTC in 30 years. 1000 USD exchange rate per BTC is just speculation..

Answer (score 1):

Whoever discovers the block can choose what information to put into it. Therefore a miner that finds a hash that has a sufficient level of difficulty can choose to only include transactions that actually pay their transaction fee.

Comment: Could they also include arbitrary data as well?

Comment: I am not quite sure, the bitcoin wiki doesn't seem to know. You seemed to have believed that you can, what lead you to believe that?